# git switch TABTAB --> List of branches in LRU order?

Tags: git, autocomplete

I if use the autocomplete feature of git (for example `git switch TABTAB`) is see the list of available branches, sorted in alphabetical order.

It would be great to have LRU (least-recently-used) order. With the branch I used some minutes ago at the top.

I my current project there are many branches, so that this feature would be really helpful.

Comment: Is your question how you can contribute a patch to the source code of Git to add this feature?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am looking for a solution, if this means patching git itself, then this is a valid answer.